# Calling POST method in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, http-post

I am new to Windows Phone 7 application development. I am trying to call a URL in my program using POST method which takes some parameters. After the successful post I am supposed to get the response in JSON format. But I am not getting the response. The code I am using is:

```cs
    public void Submit()
    {
        // Prepare web request...
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(someUrl, UriKind.Absolute));
        myRequest.Method = "POST";
        myRequest.ContentType = string.Format("multipart/form-data; boundary={0}", boundary);

        myRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), myRequest);
    }


    public string url { get; set; }
    private Dictionary<string, string> _parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public Dictionary<string, string> parameters
    {
        get { return _parameters; }
        set { _parameters = value; }
    }

    string boundary = "----------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();


    private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
        parameters.Add("userid", "0");
        parameters.Add("locationid", "0");
        writeMultipartObject(postStream, parameters);
        postStream.Close();

        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
    }

    private void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
        Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
        streamResponse.Close();
        streamRead.Close();
        // Release the HttpWebResponse
        response.Close();
    }

    public void writeMultipartObject(Stream stream, object data)
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        if (data != null)
        {
            foreach (var entry in data as Dictionary<string, string>)
            {
                WriteEntry(writer, entry.Key, entry.Value);
            }
        }
        writer.Write("--");
        writer.Write(boundary);
        writer.WriteLine("--");
        writer.Flush();
    }

    private void WriteEntry(StreamWriter writer, string key, object value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            writer.Write("--");
            writer.WriteLine(boundary);
            if (value is byte[])
            {
                byte[] ba = value as byte[];

                writer.WriteLine(@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""{0}""; filename=""{1}""", key, "sentPhoto.jpg");
                writer.WriteLine(@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
                //writer.WriteLine(@"Content-Type: image / jpeg");
                writer.WriteLine(@"Content-Length: " + ba.Length);
                writer.WriteLine();
                writer.Flush();
                Stream output = writer.BaseStream;

                output.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);
                output.Flush();
                writer.WriteLine();
            }
            else
            {
                writer.WriteLine(@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""{0}""", key);
                writer.WriteLine();
                writer.WriteLine(value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

I cannot find what the real problem is. Anybody out there to help me out?

Comment: Hi, are you able to confirm that the web server is responding to your post? In your code, it seems that you are performing your request correctly yet you don't seem to being adding any data to the body of the request. Which is what a POST should be doing. It's possible that the server isn't accepting your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution as:

```
   {
        Dictionary<string, object> param = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        param.Add(DataHolder.USER_ID, "0");
        param.Add(DataHolder.DEFAULT_LOCATION_ID, "0");
        PostClient proxy = new PostClient(param);
        proxy.DownloadStringCompleted += new PostClient.DownloadStringCompletedHandler(proxy_DownloadStringCompleted);           
        proxy.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(DataHolder.mainConfigFetchUrl, UriKind.Absolute));





    }

    void proxy_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            //Process the result... 
            string data = e.Result;
        }
    }
```

For PostClient we will need a WindowsPhonePostClient.dll which can be obtained from http://postclient.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a 'real' answer, but I always use: http://postclient.codeplex.com/ when dealing with Posts. This just to be sure I don't write any faults with the Request code.
Just give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This example come from http://northernlights.codeplex.com

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Send error report (exception) to HTTP endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uri">The Endpoint to report to.</param>
    /// <param name="exception">Exception to send.</param>
    public void SendExceptionToHttpEndpoint(string uri, ExceptionContainer exception)
    {
        if (!this.AllowAnonymousHttpReporting)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(
                r =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        HttpWebRequest request1 = (HttpWebRequest)r.AsyncState;
                        Stream postStream = request1.EndGetRequestStream(r);

                        string info = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{1}AppVersion: {3}{1}", exception.Message, Environment.NewLine, exception.StackTrace, exception.AppVersion);

                        string postData = "&exception=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(info);
                        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

                        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                        postStream.Close();

                        request1.BeginGetResponse(
                            s =>
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    HttpWebRequest request2 = (HttpWebRequest)s.AsyncState;
                                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request2.EndGetResponse(s);

                                    Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
                                    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
                                    string response2 = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                                    streamResponse.Close();
                                    streamReader.Close();
                                    response.Close();
                                }
                                catch
                                {
                                }
                            },
                        request1);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                },
            webRequest);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

It shows you how to post.

Comment: Why are you catching and then discarding exceptions? Is it safe to ignore these exceptions?

Comment: In this case it's not that important that the POST succeeds. this code is used to report previous exception to the developer of a windows phone app.  You can ofcourse add your own exception handling in here.

Answer (score 0):

WP7 ships with the "Reactive Extensions" that is helpful with asynch interactions in general. This sample http://wp7guide.codeplex.com shows how to use it for HTTP Posts (and other things)

Caveat: the sample is for a rather advanced app, and is meant to show many other things like unit testing, using the MVVM pattern, etc. It might be more sophisticated than what you need.